# Daily budget for a week in Las Vegas?

Tags: budget, planning, las-vegas

I am planning a week (Wednesday to Wednesday or Tuesday to Tuesday) in Las Vegas later this year (2017) and am wondering what sort of budget I should aim for.

Assume:

- All accommodation is paid for.
- Shows and attractions are paid for.
- Gambling will be done, maybe an hour a day - mostly on the Blackjack
  table (lowest stake available) or slot machines (I will join one
  Poker tournament but entry will be prepaid).
- Food can be basic, buffets are good.
- Alcohol intake will be relatively high. We tend to drink about 5-10 liters (10-20 pints) of beer per night and I am sure there will be a bit of tequila and whisky in there too, although a couple of low intake days may also be included due to hang overs.

I expect to spend most of my time on The Strip or Fremont Street but off the strip ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Get the buffet passes for any hotel on the strip. They rock.

Comment: @GayotFow any links to these passes?

Comment: I won't Answer cuz it'll get downvoted for not being able to quote official sources, but...for what you describe, I would allow at least $350 USD.